# Vuetify breadcrumbs text color

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm trying to have different text colors for my breadcrumbs based on a property but I can't figure out how to apply those colors anywhere. Can't add a color or class in the items either.

```
breadcrumbItems() {
  return [
    {
      text: this.$t("receiving.breadcrumbs.step1"),
      disabled: this.item.Status !== "STEP1"
    },
    {
      text: this.$t("receiving.breadcrumbs.step2"),
      disabled: this.item.Status !== "STEP2"
    },
    {
      text: this.$t("receiving.breadcrumbs.step3"),
      disabled: this.item.Status !== "STEP3"
    }
  ];
}

<v-breadcrumbs :items="breadcrumbItems" class="breadStyle">
  <template v-slot:divider>
    <v-icon size="25">mdi-forward</v-icon>
  </template>
</v-breadcrumbs>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the API for v-breadcrumbs: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-breadcrumbs-item/ it doesn't provide a property "color" or something similar, but there is a slot, so you can pass any kind of components in it.

You can create a `<span>` and customize its color and its style depending on the items:

```
<template>
  <v-breadcrumbs :items="items">
    <template v-slot:divider>
      <v-icon size="25">mdi-forward</v-icon>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
      <v-breadcrumbs-item :disabled="item.disabled">
        <span :style="`color: ${item.color}`">
          {{ item.text.toUpperCase() }}
        </span>
      </v-breadcrumbs-item>
    </template>
  </v-breadcrumbs>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    items: [
      {
        text: "Dashboard",
        disabled: false,
        color: "green",
      },
      {
        text: "Link 1",
        disabled: false,
        color: "blue",
      },
      {
        text: "Link 2",
        disabled: true,
        color: "red",
      },
    ],
  }),
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. I added a switch statement in created() to activate the color depending on a prop variable and it works great.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that the deep selector (https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors) often helps with styling Vuetify components. I added this to my components scoped CSS and the colours work just fine for links:

```
.v-breadcrumbs:deep(a) {
    color: purple;
}
```

I found the relevant tag by looking through the Elements-tab under Inspect (in Chrome).

I don't know if this is the best solution for your specific situation, but figured I'd add this for anyone with a simpler use case.